# Power stage design

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, switching-regulator

My question is related to how to select topology and component for the following problem:

**The Specification**
Design a power supply:

output 5v @ 40mA & 12v@ 4 mA.

Input power supply 20v 15mA.

**Questions**

How could i achieve this design and guarentee only a 0,03 w of losses?

What's the best topology or cascade architecture do you recommand?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Theoretically, Buck converters could do it. But at this small power level, it'll be hard to keep quisicient currents in check, especially with 20 V input. If the load is constant, you can skip the control/regulation part and run both converters at constant frequency and duty cycle.

Comment: Hello Tobalt,

Thank you for your response. I tried to do a simulation with ltspice but i saw that in startup it calls much current.
I added a picture on that . take a look to the simulation. I'm worried if that will make some trouble

Comment: Is this an academic or practical question? If practical, I'm suspicious of the input current being specified so tightly, and why a 20V source can't afford more. If academic, what sources, selection of parts, and range of loads, are you required to test at? If precisely that output condition alone, a fixed duty cycle into synchronous MOSFETs will easily do it, and inductors and capacitors can be made as large and ideal as you like.

Comment: This is not an academic projet :( 
It's a real project. I've been scratching my head for more than two weeks and the goal is to power up a sensor with 12v and a microcontroller with other some stuff with 5v.
Yes the maximum power supply is 20V and i can not have more than 15 mA.
I tried many buck converter but none of them works.
Have limited power source to 15mA in ltspice the buck dosen't start up

Comment: These conditions are pretty much on edge and it is a) unlikely that an integrated buck controller will do this at the required efficiency and b) that a spice model of an IC will be accurate enough to rely on for such an edge case. Better make your own oscillator and MOSFET, with fixed duty cycle.

Comment: Do you need a regulated 12V or ist it possible to create this from a secondary winding of the 5 V buck converter?

Comment: @R_Hjr So you mean the efficiency must be \$\frac{5\:\text{V}\,\cdot\, 40\:\text{mA}\,+\,12\:\text{V}\,\cdot\, 4\:\text{mA}}{5\:\text{V}\,\cdot\, 40\:\text{mA}\,+\,12\:\text{V}\,\cdot\, 4\:\text{mA}\,+\,30\:\text{mW}}\approx 89.2\,\%\$ or better? Essentially 90%?

Comment: It's possible to create this from one of those output @Jens

Comment: I think the best way is to have a efficiency of > 90% due to the power loss of buck stages components @jonk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to simulate a circuit that provides the required outputs, but with an input current of about 22 mA instead of the requested 15 mA. There is a current limiting circuit that actually allows 70 mA at startup, but then it limits to about 20 mA after 15 mSec. A comparator inhibits the buck switching converters as the capacitor C2 charges up. I'm sure it's possible to make a better current limiter and tweak some values to better approach the required parameters.

[image: Buck converter LT3631]

Actually, the current sense resistor accounts for about 86 mW extra power. But without it, the 20V supply draws about 29 mA due to lots of transients. I tried adding an inductor to the input but that made it worse.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick simulation without putting a lot of effort into optimizing it.

The value of the input capacitor seems to matter in the simulation, I reduced it to 2.2\$\mu\$F and it reduced the supply current, I don't know if this improvement will translate to hardware though. I also removed the 2 Meg resistor as it didn't seem to matter.

I chained the 5 V regulator off of the 12 V one. I tried running it from the 20 V, the supply current was slightly lower but had some spurious spikes.

It looks like it might be possible. You need around 83% overall efficiency, the LT3631 data sheet shows it doing better than that. As tobalt said, it's on the edge, you've got a pretty slim margin to work with.

Note that the average current is within your specs, but the peak is ~220 mA. If you're spec is based on peak you're probably up the proverbial creek.

[image]

Comment: The peak current at start-up might be reduced to within spec by implementing a current-limited precharge of a large capacitor

Comment: @PStechPaul I took another look at it, when I reduced the capacitance I had been including the first 10ms before it was stable, looking at just the stable part a larger cap appears to reduce the peak current but the average stays about the same.

Comment: @GodJihyo I don't get your 83%. See my comment to the OP, above, for the calculation and the result I see. Seems closer to 90% to me.

Comment: @PStechPaul I Tried some circuit that i found but it's seems that they don't do the stuff. Could you draw a sample ?

Comment: @jonk For the efficiency formula η = Pout / Pin I used 20V x 15mA for Pin, you used Pout + 30mW. I'm not sure where the OP got that value, could be leaving a safety margin, could have just been spitballing it. So I guess it's 83% best case, 90% worst case.